# Microphone not working in Mac Mini

Tags: macos, mac

I am having a Mac Mini Mid 2011 Model.Earlier I was having 10.7.5 OS,my microphone was working Fine.But recently i Updated my system to Yosemite 
10.10.2 and my microphone stopped working.In System Preferences-->Sound-->Input i am getting 
Line In(Name)              Audio Line-IN port(TYPE)
I am using Iball headphones.

Comment: try - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122337/macbook-pro-volume-greyed-out-no-internal-speakers-available

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "iball headphones" are, but this is a common problem with USB mic's.  There is a temporary workaround (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602025?start=45&tstart=2), and it's worked for me.

In summary, type: `sudo killall coreaudiod`